# How to pass image from Angular(2/4) to in ASP.NET Core WebAPI server folder

Tags: angular, file-upload, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

My file is in the following format in Angular end:

```
let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];

let input = new FormData();
input.append("file", fileToUpload);

return this.http.post(uploadUrl, input);
```

And my API in ASP.NET CORE is:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject objData)
{
    dynamic jsonData = objData;
    JObject FileJson = jsonData.jsonFile; // JSON File

    // Please suggest how to store the file in Folder
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: generally we wouldn't send the `Image` as a `Json` format but in the form of the `muti-part` and using the `stream-object` you can save the image in the server

Comment: Yes!! I figured that out. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. So I am posting the answer so that it can help out others.

This is my complete code in **ASP.NET Core API Controller** :

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public FileUploadController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
    {

        long size = 0;

            var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                            .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                            .FileName
                            .Trim('"');


        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;

        var filePath = webRoot + "/Uploads" + $@"/{ filename}";

        bool fileExists = (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) ? true : false);

        if (fileExists)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var randomNum = random.Next(99999);
            filename = randomNum +filename;
            filePath = webRoot + "/Uploads" + $@"/{ filename}";
        }
        size += file.Length;
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }
        return Ok(filename);
    }
}
```

This in my **Image Upload service** in Angular:

```
export class UploadService {
   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   public upload = function (fileToUpload: any, uploadUrl) {

     let input = new FormData();
     input.append("file", fileToUpload);

     return this.http.post(uploadUrl, input);
   }
}
```

This is my *documentSubmit* function in **Angular component** :

`import { UploadService } from './Upload.service';`

`constructor(private http: Http,private uploadService: UploadService) { }`

`@ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;`

```
onDocumentSubmit = function () {

  let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

  if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {

  let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];

  this.uploadService.upload(fileToUpload, ConstantComponent.url + "/FileUpload")
    .subscribe(data => {

      let documentDetails = {
        PodId: this.podId,
        DocumentName: fileToUpload.name,
        DocumentPath: ConstantComponent.port + "/Uploads/" + data._body,
      }
      this.http.post(ConstantComponent.url + "/DocumentManagerAPI/Add", documentDetails, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("success")

        }, error => {
          console.log("error")

        });
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my File Input **HTML** :

`<input #fileInput type="file" name="document" [(ngModel)]="document" />`